# Add new line in php list

Tags: php, html

I had some help from users here creating a website that creates a template for the chef at my facility for the menus. It is all working great except for when he tries to enter multi line items..

```
Example:
Main Item
Side 1
Side 2

Comes out as:
Main Item Side 1 Side 2
```

Here's my script I'm using:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>GCH Cafe Menu</title>

<style>
.menu {
background: url(bg2.jpg);
width: 1024;
height: 768;
padding: 20px 570px 50px 50px;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu h2 {
 font-size: 18px;
}


<?php
$MessageMonday = $_POST['MessageMonday'];
$MessageTuesday = $_POST['MessageTuesday'];
$MessageWednesday= $_POST['MessageWednesday'];
$MessageThursday = $_POST['MessageThursday'];
$MessageFriday = $_POST['MessageFriday'];

ob_start();
?>


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="height: 768px" class="menu">
<br />
<h2><center><font size="24">GCH Cafe Menu</font></center></h2>
<br />
<p><h2><font face="lucida calligraphy"><u>Monday</h2></u></font></p>
<div> <?php echo $MessageMonday; ?></div>
<br />


<p><h2><font face="lucida calligraphy"><u>Tuesday</h2></u></font></p>
<div> <?php echo $MessageTuesday; ?></div>
<br />


<p><h2><font face="lucida calligraphy"><u>Wednesday</h2></u></font></p>
<div> <?php echo $MessageWednesday; ?></div>
<br />


<p><h2><font face="lucida calligraphy"><u>Thursday</h2></u></font></p>
<div> <?php echo $MessageThursday; ?></div>
<br />


<p><h2><font face="lucida calligraphy"><u>Friday</h2></u></font></p>
<div><?php echo $MessageFriday; ?></div>
<br />

</body>
</html>

<?php
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$filename = "menu.html";

file_put_contents($filename, $html);

echo file_get_contents("menu.html");
?>
```

Comment: Try changing potential new lines (HTML don't care about normal line breaks) to actual HTML break tags `nl2br($multiLineString)`

Comment: Also, since you're using a stylesheet, every single thing you have between the H2 tags should be defined in the styles.  Your markup is invalid to start with.  Putting all that in the class will solve all that.

Comment: Where would I add that @JimL ? In the spot like `<?php ehco $MessageMonday; nl2br($multiLineString); ?>`

Comment: `<?php echo nl2br($MessageFriday); ?>` or simply `<?= nl2br($MessageFriday); ?>` (using a shorthand echo)

Comment: That did it! Thanks @JimL -  I'm still learning CSS and everything so I will play around with cleaning up this code as well. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Great, if you use the code you originally had, you can actually see the line breaks if you "view source". But as said, HTML don't care about them so you lose the line breaks on the normal web site